# Dictionaries for conversions of numbers with M and K to int in a new list

Tags: python

Thanks for dropping in this post.

I'm flummoxed with how to pass list members that includes string  with K and M.

I need to convert those strings with K and M into integers while those with purely string is kept as it is.

So for example I have a list:

> sales = ['No data', '300K', '5M', '3B']

into

> updated_sales = ['No data', 300000, 5000000, 3000000000]

I've tried this code:

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

suffix = {"M": 1000000,
          "B": 1000000000,
          "K": 1000
              }
def updsales(saleslist):
  updated_sales=[]
  for sale in saleslist:
    if sale[-1] in suffix:
      sales_value,magnitude = sale[:-1], sale[-1]
      return updated_sales.append(Decimal(sales_value) * 10 ** suffix[magnitude])
    else:
      return updated_sales.append('No Data')

sales = ['No data', '300K', '5M', '3B']
updsales(sales)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modifications in your code:

```
def updsales(saleslist):
    updated_sales=[]
    for sale in saleslist:
        if sale[-1] in suffix:
            sales_value,magnitude = sale[:-1], sale[-1]
            updated_sales.append(int(sales_value) *  suffix[magnitude])
        else:
            updated_sales.append('No Data')
    return updated_sales

updsales(['No data', '300K', '5M', '3B'])
```

Output:

```
['No Data', 300000, 5000000, 3000000000]
```

### What you were doing wrong?

1. Returning the append list instead of the entire list
2. Using `10 **` even though you'd stored the required zeros in `suffix`.

### However, if you are interested.
Here's a simpler implementation :

```
suffix = {'B' : 'e9', 'M': 'e6', 'K': 'e3'}
def updsales(saleslist):
    updated_sales = []
    for i, val in enumerate(saleslist):
        if val[-1] in suffix:
            updated_sales.append(float(val[:-1] + suffix[val[-1]]))
        else:
            updated_sales.append(val)
    return updated_sales

updsales(['No data', '300K', '5M', '3B'])
```

Output:

```
['No data', 300000.0, 5000000.0, 3000000000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct:

```
suffix = {"M": 1000000,
          "B": 1000000000,
          "K": 1000
              }
def updsales(saleslist):
    updated_sales=[]
    for sale in saleslist:
        if sale[-1] in suffix:
            sales_value,magnitude = sale[:-1], sale[-1]
            updated_sales.append(float(sales_value) *  suffix[magnitude])
        else:
            updated_sales.append('No Data')
    return updated_sales

sales = ['No data', '300K', '5M', '3B']
print(updsales(sales))
```

You needed 2 changes:

1. Don't return the appends, return the fully updated list **after** the for loop
2. You were doing `10 ** ...` when the suffix list already contains the complete multiplier.

I changed `Decimal` with `float`, and you could even just use `int` in this case.